# What is a z-score

Tags: z-score

I have incorrectly been referring to z-scores as quantiles from a standard normal distribution.

Is it possible to discuss this further?

Comment: "Is it possible to discuss this further?" is overly broad. Can you be more specific about what the circumstances are that you're referring to? There *are* some situations where the term 'z-score' does refer to  a quantile from a standard normal distribution, but then there's the standardized score produced by subtracting a mean and dividing by a standard deviation (whether or not we're dealing with normal distributions). ... [I don't think these should be called z-scores *unless* we're treating them as normal, but they are.]

Comment: @Glen_b, Wikipedia says `Standard scores are also called z-values, z-scores, normal scores, and standardized variables. `   This is very confusing

Comment: z-scores are often used to compare deviations for some measurement with deviations for a normal distribution. In that case one often relates to percentile scores. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68-95-99.7_rule

Answer (score 2):

The z score is defined as

$$z(x)=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$

where $\mu$ is the distribution mean and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. These may be analytical values, or estimated from the data.

This makes most sense for normal distributed, symmetric data, but can be used with other distributions.

It's easy to see that the value range is $-\infty:\infty$, so it cannot be quantiles. Also, this obviously is a linear transformation. Instead values like -1 mean "one standard deviation below the mean v.

Answer (score 0):

It is a score that indicates how many standard deviations an element is below or above the population mean. 
For example, a z-score less than zero represents an element which is less than the mean. A z-score greater than zero represents an element greater than the mean. A z-score equal to zero represents an element equal to the mean.